# Why doesn't node run javascript functions in my terminal or browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js to run JavaScript in my terminal. When I run the following JavaScript file (testfile.js) in my terminal with the command "node testfile.js", here's what I get:

```
console.log("meh");

=> meh
```

So that works fine. But when I make it a function like this:

```
function sayMeh() {
    console.log("meh");
};

sayMeh;

=>
```

I get no result. Why? How can I test JS to see if it works?

Comment: `sayMeh` will return function `expression`, Use parenthesis `()` after function name to call that function..

Comment: @RayonDabre more specifically it will return a reference to the function that is a value you can hand around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *call* the function, not just mention it.

```
sayMeh();
```

Comment: Oh, for cryin in the soup... Thank you!!